# Need to extend properties from one object to another with out over writing existing objects if they share the key name

Tags: javascript

Hey I am having a ton of trouble solving this problem:

Write a function called "extend".

Given two objects, "extend" adds properties from the 2nd object to the 1st object.

Notes:
* Add any keys that are not in the 1st object.
* If the 1st object already has a given key, ignore it (do not overwrite the property value).
* Do not modify the 2nd object at all.

```
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

extend(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1); // --> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
console.log(obj2); // --> {b: 4, c: 3}
```

So far I have this:

```
obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
obj2 = {b: 4, c: 3, d: 4};

function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  var keyz1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  var keyz2 = Object.keys(obj2);

  for (var i = 0; i < keyz2.length; i++){
    if (keyz1.indexOf(keyz2[i]) === -1) {
      var searchKey = keyz2[i];
      for (searchKey in obj2) {
        obj1[searchKey] = obj2[searchKey];
      }
    }
  }
  return obj1;
}
```

I believe it something to do with my actual

```
obj1[searchKey] = obj2[searchKey];
```

but I'm having trouble figuring out how to fix it.

Comment: What do you think `var searchKey = keyz2[i]; for (searchKey in obj2) {}` does exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could use only one keys array and use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) for checking if the key is already in the target object. If not assign the value of `source`.

While Javascript uses the reference of an object, you need not to return the target object.

```js
function extend(target, source) {
    var keys = Object.keys(source);

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (!(keys[i] in target)) {
            target[keys[i]] = source[keys[i]];
        }
    }
}

var obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
    obj2 = { b: 4, c: 3, d: 4 };

extend(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even easier:

```
function extend(target, source) {
  for(var key in source) {
    if(!target.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      target[key] = source[key];  
    }
  }

  return target;
}
```

Comment: syntax error on the 3rd line, otherwise this works. you need to use parans instead of square brackets !target.hasOwnProperty(key)

Answer (score 0):

```
  var searchKey = keyz2[i];
  for (searchKey in obj2) {
    obj1[searchKey] = obj2[searchKey];
  }
```

is a touch incorrect. It appears to be saying "for every key in the second object, overwrite the first object". Instead you could say "If the key present in the second object is not available in the first, add it to the first object"

```
if (keyz1.indexOf(keyz2[i]) === -1) {
  obj1[keyz2[i]] = obj2[keyz2[i]];        
}
```

```js
obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};

function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  var keyz1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  var keyz2 = Object.keys(obj2);

  for (var i = 0; i < keyz2.length; i++) {
    var searchKey = keyz2[i];
    if (keyz1.indexOf(searchKey) === -1) {
      obj1[searchKey] = obj2[searchKey];        
    }
  }
  return obj1;
}

console.log(extend(obj1, obj2));
```